# number of ways to write a sum of $3$ numbers that sum to $10$, such that none can be empty? $ \geqslant 1$

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there of writing the number 10 as
a sum of 3 numbers (none of which may be empty)?

where we can write as this equation $x_1+x_2+x_3=10$,  such that $x$'s have to be at least greater than $1$.  so is this the same as $x_1+x_2+x_3=7$  where $\binom{3+7-1}{7}$ ?

Comment: Might [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) help you?

Comment: " such that no x's have to be at least greater than 1"  Not sure what this means. "so is this the same as"  Probably.  ... or not.... I think the number of was to add to $7$ so that each is at least one and not $0$ is ${7\choose 3}={7+3 - 3\choose 7}$ and not ${7+3-1\choose 7}$.  Read up on stars and bars.

Comment: What's up with the "Einstein,.." in the beginning?

Comment: Based on your answer, it seems you want to say $x_1+x_2+x_3=10$ such that all the three numbers are at least $1$ or not $0$. If so, you answer $\binom{3+7-1}{7}$ is correct.

Comment: The wording of your question does not make sense.  What you have counted is the number of solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 10$ in the positive integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1st Problem*

The number of integer solutions of

> $ n_1 + n_2 + \cdots + n_n = m $ (*)

is equivalent to the *problem of establishing the number of ways to allocate m balls in n boxes*.

*Solution*

$ C_{n,m}^r = {n + m -1 \choose m}={n + m -1 \choose n-1}$

remembering that $ C_{n,k}^r = {n \choose k}={n \choose n-k}$

*2nd Problem*

What is the number of integer solutions of (*) so that

> $\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
> n_1 + n_2 + \cdots + n_n = m \\
> n_i \geq r_i & i=1,…,n \\
> r_i \in Z \\
> \end{array} \right. $

*Solution*

Let $ z_i=n_i-r_i \geq 0$, equation (*) cab be writte as

> $ z_1 + z_2 + \cdots + z_n = m – r $
> with $z_i \geq 0$ and $r=\sum_{i=1}^n r_i $

*Solution*

$ C_{n,m}^r = {n + m – r - 1 \choose m-r}={n + m -r - 1 \choose n-1}$

In your case, we have $n=3$, $m=10$, $r_i = 1$ for all $i=1, \cdots, n$ and $r=3$.
The answer is:

> $ C_{n,m}^r = {3 + 10 – 3 - 1 \choose 10-3}={9 \choose 2}$